# Jquery checked property always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Edited because I'm still getting an error:

I have a textbox that is dynamically added to a Jquery Data Table in an external javascript file.

The 'checked' property always returns undefined, even when it is defaulted to be checked.

```js
$('#Table tbody tr').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).children().eq(5).html(), $(this).children().eq(5).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked class="profiles-checkboxes" /></td>
```

Returns the following, when the input is checked to begin with:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="" class="profiles-checkboxes"> undefined
```

Comment: Won't that code always set the checkbox back to it's original state? When you check it, it returns checked as true, then you set to false. So it will never be checked, right?

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, that is correct. By the time the OP enters the click handler, the value has already changed, and they are immediately setting it back to the original value

Comment: I guess what @tymeJV tries to say is: this is not necessary: `$(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).children().eq(5)` is the `<td>`, which doesn't have a `checked` property. You need to get the property from the `<input>` inside it.

```
$(this).children().eq(5).children(":checkbox").prop("checked")
```